# Older iOS Simulator returns FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain code=1 to Deco

Tags: react-native, ios-simulator

Have been building a react-native app in Deco with iOS. iPhone 6+, 6 and 5s work fine, however anything older shows the following message:

```
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain, code=1):
The operation couldn’t be completed. (FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain error 1.)
```

Have seen other posts around this error, however none are using react-native / deco. The simulators have been wiped with no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is with the compilation. Deco 1.1.2 doesn't bother to completely recompile the client code when you launch a new simulator, so when I last compiled from the command line and it generated the app, it generated a 32bit version. I'm guessing that iPhone 5s and higher are 64bit.

Simplest solution was to force a re-compile from the command line as follows:

```
react-native run-ios --simulator "iPhone 4s"
```

Comment: this worked for me when I was having the exact same problem.